# How to call method of generic class from non generic class using dynamic?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I want to call a method of generic class from non generic class which doesn't know the type.

```
interface IShape
{
    SomeType AProperty;     // Edit 2, sorry this should be a property.
}

interface IShapeEditor
{
}

class ShapeEditorBase : IShapeEditor
{
}

class RectangleEditor<T> : ShapeEditorBase where T : IShape
{
    void Offset(T shape, int x, int y)
    {
    }
}

// This class must not be a generic class.
class OffsetRectangleButton
{
    void ButtonPressed(IShapeEditor editor)
    {
        IShape shape = ashape; // from somewhere
        dynamic editorInstance = editor;
        editorInstance.Offset(shape, 1, 1); // Will trigger an exception here!
    }
}
```

But it triggered an exception, it said C# cannot find Offset method in ShapeEditorBase.
Why is it not the RectangleEditor, but ShapeEditorBase?
How can I solve that problem? Or maybe a refactoring suggestion?

If possible without reflection (I heard it is not good).

===================

Edit for additional information:
- All code snippets are in a framework which is a Control.
- Application gives type via generic
- OffsetRectangleButton or other buttons for rectangle know everything about the methods because they are in a component/dll.

====================

Edit 3
- Make the code as similar as possible to the problem
- I rewrite the code to make the previous answers understandable instead of editing the previous code
- Please see OffsetRectangleAction
- Question: Is the interface IRectangleEditor is correct? (And I can continue to solve OffsetRectangleAction)
- Question: Or there are better solution?

```
// =========================================
// Shape Display Component (a Winform Panel)
// =========================================

// In reality, rectangle is very complex implementation.
interface IRectangle // For rectangle display
{
    Rectangle Rectangle { get; set; }
}

interface ILine // ICircle etc for other displays
{
    Line Line { get; set; }
}

// Edit/Offset actions interface. It is represented by a button.
interface IAction
{
    void Run(IShapeDisplay display);
}

// Container of all display's actions.
interface IActionContainer
{
    IList<IAction> Actions; // Every action is related to a control (button, edit box, etc).
}   

// Please see "OffsetRectangleAction".
// This class is container of all RectangleDisplays actions (as buttons in UI).
// This is also important, because this class shows why OffsetRectangleAction must not be generic.
// If OffsetRectangleAction is generic, then this class must be generic because it has OffsetRectangleAction.
// If this class generic, then in user interface has more than one OffsetRectangleAction buttons are created.
// And each OffsetRectangleAction edit certain type of Rectangle generic.
class RectangleActionContainer : IActionContainer
{
    // List of all actions/buttons
    IList<IAction> Actions;    

    RectangleActionContainer()
    {
        // It must be able to edit various types of rectangle.
        this.Actions.Add(new EditAction());
        this.Actions.Add(new OffsetRectangleAction());
    }
}

// This class must not be a generic class. Please see RectangleActionContainer class.
// This is the most important problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// How can I access RectangleDisplay.RetctangleEditor.Offset or Edit
class OffsetRectangleAction: IAction // Similar also EditRectangleAction, InflateRectangleAction
{
    void Run(IShapeDisplay display)
    {
        IRectangle rectangle = this.GelectedRectangle(); // from somewhere

        // How to make it runs properly without exception.
        dynamic rectangleDisplayInstance = display;
        dynamic editHandler = rectangleDisplayInstance.EditHandler;
        editHandler.Offset(rectangle, 1, 1); // Will trigger an exception here!
    }
}

// RectangleEditor interface to edit rectangles and as rectangles container.
interface IRectangleEditor<T> where T : IRectangle // Generic because there are many type rectangle for various purposes. 
{
    IList<T> Rectangles { get; } // List of rectangle to be edited/visualized.

    Edit(T rect, Rectangle dimension);  

    Offset(T rect, double x, double y);
}

// Shape display interface
interface IShapeDisplay
{
    IActionContainer ActionContainer { get; }

    void Draw(Graphics canvas);
}

// Base of all displays (rectangle, line, circle)
class ShapeDisplayBase : IShapeDisplay
{
    IActionContainer ActionContainer { get; private set; }

    virtual void Draw(Graphics canvas)
    {
    }
}

// Rectangle Display.
// Controller for displaying and bussines logic of rectangle shapes.
// ShapeDisplayBase inherited also for Line, Circular etc displays.
class RectangleDisplay<T> : ShapeDisplayBase where T : IShape
{
    IRectangleEditor<T> RectangleEditor { get; private set; }

    RectangleDisplay<T>(IRectangleEditor<T> editor)
    {
        this.RectangleEditor = editor;
    }

    override void Draw(Graphics canvas)
    {
    }
}

// Controller for the whole shape displays (Rectangle, Line, Circle etc.)
class ShapeDisplaysController
{
    IList<IActionContainer> ActionContainers { get; private set; } // Action container for all displays (rectangle, line, etc)

    IList<IShapeDisplay> ShapeDisplays { get; private set; } // Can be RectangleDisplay, LineDisplay, CircularDisplay

    void RegisterDisplay(IShapeDisplay display)
    {
       this.ShapeDisplays = display;

       // A type of displays can only one action container (eg: many rectangle types can be edited only with one edit button)
       if (!ActionContainer.Contains(display))
       {
           ActionContainers.Add(display.ActionContainer);
       }
    }

    // Show all shape display objects.
    void Draw(Graphics canvas)
    {
        foreach(var display in this.ShapeDisplays)
        {
            display.Draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}

// ==========================
// Application 
// ==========================

class RoundedRectangleEditHandler<T> : IRectangleEditor<T> where T : IRectangle
{
     IList<T> Rectangles { get; private set;} // List of rectangle to be edited/visualized.
     implementation...
}

class FillRectangleEditHandler<T> : IRectangleEditor<T> where T : IRectangle
{
     IList<T> Rectangles { get; private set;} // List of rectangle to be edited/visualized.
     implementation...
}

// There are many application that use ShapeViewer component.
// And every application has their own rectangle type, so we decided to use generic.
class ShapeViewerApp: Form
{
    // Visualization control for shape.
    private ShapeDisplaysController myShapeDisplaysController;

    // Show shape list in grid.
    private GridController myGridController;

    static void Main()
    {
        this.myShapeDisplaysController = new ShapeDisplaysController();

         var roundedRectangleEditHandler = new RoundedRectangleEditHandler<RoundedRect>();
         var roundedRectangleDisplay = new RoundedRectangleDisplay<RoundedRect>(roundedRectangleEditHandler);

         var fillRectangleEditHandler = new FillRectangleEditHandler<FillRectangle>();
         var fillRectangleDisplay = new FillRectangleDisplay<FillRectangle>(fillRectangleEditHandler);           

         this.myShapeDisplaysController.Register(fillRectangleDisplay);
         this.myShapeDisplaysController.Register(roundedRectangleDisplay);
         this.myShapeDisplaysController.Register(lineDisplay);
         this.myShapeDisplaysController.Register(circleDisplay);

         // ShapeDisplaysController is a Winform Panel UI.
         this.Controls.Add(this.myShapeDisplaysController.Control);
         this.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `dynamic` if you know that `editor` implements `IShapeEditor`? It seems you will already know what methods are available in that case.

Comment: It sounds like the editor is *actually* an instance of `ShapeEditorBase` rather than `RectangleEditor<T>`. It would help if you provided a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: First, I don't know who told you that reflection is not good, but that is not good advice. Anyway, it is not what you need here. The problem is that whatever you pass to `ButtonPressed` (`editor`) is not a `RectangleEditor<T>`, so it has no method called `Offset`. And you did not show us how you are calling that method, so we cannot help more.

Comment: Fyi: this is a valid use of `dynamic` although static solutions are preferred because of the maintenance advantages and other things.

Comment: @Jason Evans, thank you. Yes the OffsetRectangleButton knows the method. But the problem is RectangleEditor is a generic class. It cannot be called directly from non generic class. This is the main problem.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, no it isn't an instance of RectangleEditor, for sure.
The problem is the whole code snippet is a component (Control). And the application use this component and give the type via generic which this component doesn't know.

Comment: @YohanesNurcahyo: Well if it isn't an instance of `RectangleEditor`, how do you expect to call a method which is only implemented in `RectangleEditor`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Sorry, I was false, I meant it is instance of RectangleEditor, I wrote it midnight. I edited the IShape and the method (Offset for example) using IShape property (generic) as parameter. Every button knows the methods in RectangleEditor (in reality there is a handler (and the button know its interface) or method library that implemented by application in generic, it is for simplicity). But because it is generic, Button class cannot access it (unkonwn type). I cannot make the whole framework as generic, impossible in my case.

Comment: It's very hard to follow what's going on. Really you should produce a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, otherwise it'll be really hard to help you further.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, even it is difficult (the real software is more than 100000 line of code and it is not common topic), I will try to simplify it. It needs time, I hope you still follow this question.

Comment: @YohanesNurcahyo: Being able to narrow down the cause of a problem is a key skill in software engineering. I'd be amazed if more than 1000 lines of that code is actually relevant to the problem - and you should be able to reproduce it in less than 100, I suspect.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I made it simpler. I hope it is simple enough to make you understand the whole problem. The problem only in a display, another display is working properly. Generic is more usable in application side than in ShapeDisplay component.<br /><br />
The edited code is mostly different with the first code.

Answer (score 1):

`IShapeEditor` doesn't contain your `Offset` method, and thus the program doesn't know that the method exists on that object. You could cast it as that type, if you were certain that's what it is and that would enable you to avoid the `dynamic` keyword.

I suggest you add the method to `IShapeEditor`, or otherwise use the exact type you care about, since the class you're implementing refers to `Rectangle`s, it only makes sense that it would be concerned about only `Rectangle`s, and not any other `IShape`.

Comment: I cannot cast to the type, because OffsetRectangleButton doesn't know the type of generic.
And I cannot add Offset method in IShapeEditor with Offset because not all editors using Offset. In this case Offset is used only for example and simplifying the question.

Answer (score 1):

How about moving  you `Offset` to `IShapeEditor` and implement it in `ShapeEditorBase`? Then you wouldn't need to use `dynamic`.

```
class ShapeEditorBase : IShapeEditor
{
    public void Offset(IShape shape, int x, int y)
    {
    }
}

class RectangleEditor<T> : ShapeEditorBase where T : IShape
{
}
```

Comment: Like my answer to Rob G, Offset or these code snippet is only for simplifying my question. Not all IShaperEditor implementation using Offset method. My real topic is not common and difficult to understand for a question.

Comment: Then you should have a common interface for all RectangleEditors that have offset and either use that as a parameter to `ButtonPressed` or try cast to it inside the function.

Comment: In real software I have already a interface/wrapper to hide the generic like you said. But some people doesn't like it, because if the editor grows, I must make additional method that maybe I can avoid if there is better solution like dynamic if it is working properly.